# String resource showing incorrect value

Tags: android, android-resources

I have following string resource defined in strings.xml

```
<string name="years">Years</string>
```

In following 2 ways i am trying to use it

```
showUserSelectedExperience.setText("0"+R.string.years);
showUserSelectedExperience.setText(String.valueOf(experience.getProgress())+R.string.years);
```

Following incorrect output i am getting

02131361882

But correct output i should get : **0 years, 1 years** like that

what can be the problem and what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 showUserSelectedExperience.setText("0"+getResources().getString( R.string.years));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `showUserSelectedExperience.setText(R.string.years);`, it will show 'Years'. That is because an integer is found (2131361882) and the correct string resource will be returned. Now, if you use this string: `"0"+R.string.years`, it's the same as concatenating the String "0" with another String. The same way that `"Year "+1` will output "Year 1". The integer R.string.years, which has 2131361882 as value, is parsed to a String with value "2131361882". That is why you are getting this result. So short: setText(integer) will get the string resource, setText(string) will show that string value. The solution is to first get the string resource, and then concatenate it.

```
String years = getString(R.string.years);
showUserSelectedExperience.setText("0"+years);
```

Same as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
showUserSelectedExperience.setText("0" + getString(R.string.years));
```